# replacing the hyphenated words in a sentence created by new lines

Tags: python, regex

```
reso- lution
sug- gest
evolu- tion
```

are all words that have contain hyphens due to limited space in a line in a piece of text. e.g.

> Analysis of two high *reso- lution* nucleosome maps revealed strong
>   signals that even though they do not constitute a definite proof are
>   at least consistent with such a view. Taken together, all these
>   findings *sug- gest* the intriguing possibility that nucleosome
>   positions are the product of a mechanical *evolu- tion* of DNA
>   molecules.

I would like to replace with their natural forms i.e.

```
resolution
suggest
evolution
```

How can I do this in a text with python?

Comment: Would a blunt code like `replace("- ","")`, work?

Comment: `s = re.sub(r'([a-z])- ([a-z])', r'\1\2', s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there is a lowercase letter before `-` and a lowercase letter after the `-`+space, capture the letters and use backreferences to get these letters back after replacement:

```
([a-z])- ([a-z])
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ULf5sm/2) (replace with `\1\2` backreference sequence). Note that you may adjust the number of spaces with `{1,max}` quantifier (say, if there is one or two spaces between the parts of the word, use `([a-z])- {1,2}([a-z])`). If there can be any whitespace, use `\s` rather than  .

[Python code](http://ideone.com/s1ymup):

```
import re
s = 'Analysis of two high reso- lution nucleosome maps revealed strong signals that even though they do not constitute a definite proof are at least consistent with such a view. Taken together, all these findings sug- gest the intriguing possibility that nucleosome positions are the product of a mechanical evolu- tion of DNA molecules.'
s = re.sub(r'([a-z])- ([a-z])', r'\1\2', s)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) to replace `"- "` with `""`. For example:

```
>>> my_text = 'reso- lution'
>>> my_text = my_text.replace('- ', '')
>>> my_text  # Updated value without "- "
'resolution'
```